# Docker (compose) : making knex work with postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, knex.js

I'm trying to dockerize a NodeJS / PostgreSQL app, but i can't run `knex` migrations, I'm getting the following error :

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:15432 
>        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1161:14)

Here is my *docker-compose.yml* :

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: users-microservice
      DB_HOST: db
  db:
    image: postgres:10.4-alpine
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: users-microservice
```

The *Dockerfile* for the 'app' service :

```
FROM node:10.1-alpine
EXPOSE 3000 9229 15432
COPY . /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g knex
CMD ./scripts/start.sh
```

and in the *start.sh*, the following command works :

```
until PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD psql -h "$DB_HOST" -U "$POSTGRES_USER" -c '\d'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
```

So I can connect to postgres through the CLI, but knex can't, why is that ? Am I getting something wrong, I'm new to Docker ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're trying to run a command inside the service `app` when you see this error message (but maybe you can specify)?

My guess then would be that you're trying to connect to `db:15432` from within `app`. Note, that saying

```
ports:
  - "15432:5432"
```

only makes sure that you can call the service from your *host* machine on port `15432`. But if you want to call the service `db` from within `app`, you still have to use `db:5432`.

Comment: Well, you're right, it seems that I still have a lot to learn about docker !

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @the-bass saved me. I'm going to include my docker-compose.yml and knexfile.js files to hopefully make this clearer for people with this issue who find this post.

What I was doing wrong was that I was not setting the host environment variable correctly in my app container. Once I changed it to just use db (the name of my postgres container) and made sure to include the port in my knexfile, all worked.

knexfile.js

```
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: "pg",
    connection: {
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
      port: 5432,
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10,
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: "./data/migrations",
    },
  },

  production: {
    client: "pg",
    connection: {
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
      port: 5432,
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10,
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: "./data/migrations",
    },
  },
};
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - my-postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=me
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=my-data

  node-app:
    image: node:12.16.2
    command: sh -c "npm install && npm install -g knex && knex migrate:latest && npm start"
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_USER=HG
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - DB_DATABASE=my-data
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db

volumes:
  my-postgres-data:
```